# Работа с библиотекой pyserial

Tags: python, serial

Задача такая: Девайс по интерфейсу RS485 соединен с ПК. На ПК запускаю Pycharm. Библиотека pyserial есть. Вот скрипт:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1)

def main():
    while True:
        s = ser.readline()
        if s == b'GETSTATUS\r':
            print(s)
            ser.write(b'\\53\54\41\54\55\53\20\31\2c\30\2c
                         \30\2c\31\2c\31\37\5c\72\4f\4b\5c\72')
        else:
            print('TIMEOUT')


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Каждые 10 секунд девайс выдает соощение `"GETSTATUS\r"`. Я его принимаю. И в ответ мне нужно отослать ему сообщение `"STATUS 1,0,0,1,17\rOK\r"`.

Параллельно  я "прослушиваю" интерфейс 485. Попробовал писать и `"STATUS 1,0,0,1,17\rOK\r"`, и `"\\53\54\41\54\55\53\20\31\2c\30\2c\30\2c\31\2c\31\37\5c\72\4f\4b\5c\72"`. Но в прослушке все время пишет `"5C 5D 55 AB 55 5D 55 65 95 FF"`.

Помогите написать ответ на запрос правильно. Опыта мало в таком деле.

Comment: может прослушка глючит?

Comment: Может и так. завтра проверю. А если с прослушкой все хорошо, то в чем проблема?

Comment: Мне все таки кажется проблема с кодировкой сообщения "STATUS 1,0,0,1,17\rOK\r". Я просто пока слабовато разбираюсь во всем этом.

Comment: Ыыы, а у Вас есть возможность поменять язык девайса? Если перекодировать ваше сообщение с 16-ричной системы, у меня получилось это `屝喫啝啥闿`

Comment: у вас там байтовая строка, она не перекодируется

Comment: проверь скорость везде

Answer (score 1):

Причина пока я так понял в том что забыл поставить в настройках COM-порта режим совместимости с RS485.

Правда код я немного подкорректировал. Вот так.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1)


def main():
    while True:
        s = ser.readline()
        if s == b'GETSTATUS\r':
            print(s)
            ser.write(b'STATUS 1,0,0,1,17\rOK\r')
        else:
            print('TIMEOUT')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```